# Float a group of divs around another layer without creating gaps

Tags: css, css-float

I have a very hard time creating a certain layout, and I am not so sure anymore if it actually works. So basically, I have a content area, and a sidebar with lots of abstracts, these boxes having different heights, depending on the content.

The abstracts should layout similar to pinterest, preferably running from left to right. The tricky part is now that these abstracts should flow **around** the content area if space permits. So, if the sidebar to the right is filled up, and the content area has ended, the following abstracts should be positioned below the content, instead of to the right.

The HTML should basically look like this:

```
<div class="page">

    <div class="content">
        <h2>CONTENT</h2>
        <p>Lorem ispsum bla bla bla</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">

        <div class="abstract"></div>
        <div class="abstract"></div>
        <div class="abstract"></div>
        <div class="abstract"></div>

        ... etc ...

    </div>

</div>
```

So what would be really important, is that the "content" layer and the "sidebar" layer should **not** be nested!

To better illustrate the problem, here are some images:

I tried to create the layout using good old floats and this is what I get:

[image]

So the floats do in fact wrap around the content, but leave some really ugly gaps.

But I'd like to have something more like this, so that the layout does not have these gaps, but tries to fill them as optimal as possible:

[image]

Any idea how to do this, maybe using more advanced CSS3, preferably without layouting via Javascript? Also tried with flexboxes, but wasn't able to create such a layout so far, so any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** created a fiddle so you can see the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtwb6/

Comment: Have you tried just floating all the little grey boxes and then floating the sidebar as a whole to the right?

Comment: Why not go with masonary plugin. It will do automatically.

Comment: What if you use `display:inline-block` instead?

Comment: @ Perry: not sure what you exactly mean, can you make an example?

@ Roopendra: would prefer a CSS only solution. And I think in this case masonry will not be enough

@ Joshua: using inline-block won't change much

Comment: Impossible to fill spaces for the float property only with CSS

Comment: possible with flex layout instead?

Comment: @frontend_dev I am not sure it is possible in css. But quite possible you can do it in masonary.

Comment: No, this is not possible with Flexbox.  It's too bad that the `column-span` property doesn't take a number (see:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).

Comment: To do it CSS you'd have to specify the position of the elements which would eliminate any flexibility in the design. Short of that you're stuck with JavaScript and plugins like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You can try http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ to

Comment: You could give column-count a try, http://jsfiddle.net/d4xT2/4/.

Comment: column-count also does not give me the desired result. So it really seems that this problem is not solvable using pure (even advanced) CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to clear the following div

```
clear:both;
```

just add that in your css to the following divs, i think it should work.

Comment: It's not about clearing, actually more about preventing that.